# Open DB Connection within Oracle SQL Developer script

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to connect to a specfic DB connection in SQL Developer from a script ?

The idea is:
I need to extend same table on 20 different DB Connections.
So the command is the same alter table xxx and it needs to be executed 20 times.

So far I can only open connection by hand and execute the script.

Note: I do not have sqlplus..

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by 'extend table'?  And why don't you have sqlplus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the CONNECT command

```
conn hr/oracle@server:1521/db
create table x (a integer);

conn hr/oracle@server:1521/db2
create table x (a integer);

...
```

At the end of your script, you'll be 'disconnected' from the 'remote' systems and placed back into the database your Worksheet was opened on.

Execute the script with F5, or the 2nd execute button on the SQL Worksheet toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dblink` to execute the DDL as follows:

```
dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@db_link('ALTER TABLE ...');
```

First, you need to create the 20 `dblinks`.

**Note**: Ideally, You should avoid DDL over `dblink`.